# BackgroundTransferService with POST method and Parameters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, file-upload, windows-phone, background-transfer

I want to **upload a file** (VideoFile) to server **through** `BackgroundTransferService`.

My problem is, I also want to **send 2 parameters** along with File (POST request).

So, is it possible to send parameters along with File upload while using `BackgroundTransferService` API..?

**Code with `BackgroundTransferService`:**

```
        BackgroundTransferRequest req = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri("ServerURL", UriKind.Absolute));
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;

        string uploadLocationPath = "/Shared/Transfers/myVideoFile.mp4";
        string downloadLocationPath = "/Shared/Transfers/response.txt";

        req.UploadLocation = new Uri(uploadLocationPath, UriKind.Relative);
        req.DownloadLocation = new Uri(downloadLocationPath, UriKind.Relative);

        req.TransferProgressChanged += req_TransferProgressChanged;
        req.TransferStatusChanged += req_TransferStatusChanged;

        try
        {
            BackgroundTransferService.Add(req);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to add video to upload queue.\nPlease try again later.", App.appName, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
```

Please ask if anyone wants more info and unable to understand my question.

I want a quick response. Yes or No.. and if Yes then How..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into similar kind of problem before few weeks. i somehow managed this file upload by `HttpClient`.

Check code

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        StorageFile file = null; // assign your file here

        MultipartFormDataContent formdata = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formdata.Add(new StringContent("value"), "key");
        formdata.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()), "file", "recordedVideoFile2.mp4");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("URL here"), formdata);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want to upload file in `Background` so i guess i have to use `BackgroundTransferService`.

Comment: I would recommend to mark your methods as `async` and simply call this method to start the background process. No need for `BackgroundTransferService` anymore.

Comment: @FlorianMoser Thanks for your inputs, but the reason i have to use `BackgroundTransferService` is i also want to track how much bytes have been uploaded and how much remains. These stats can be tracked only if we use BackgroundTransferService, not through `HttpClient`. Is there any other alternative..?

Comment: It seems like HttpClient can do this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169573/how-to-implement-progress-reporting-for-portable-httpclient

Comment: sounds great..! I'm trying to apply it on my case.. let's see if it works..
I'll mention here soon..!

Comment: sadly, I've to use `HttpClient` and complete the upload with POST request (with few limitation). @FlorianMoser thanks for your reference links. that helped me solve my other problem. @learner thanks for suggesting alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure on what you are trying to do. However, I believe you can via HTTP Headers.

BackgroundTransferRequest.Headers Property
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferrequest.headers(v=vs.105).aspx

And as the sender with the Tag Property.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferrequest.tag(v=vs.105).aspx

> This property can be used to associate custom data associated with a
>   transfer. The application can set the value when the transfer request
>   is created. When the transfer request is retrieved, using the Requests
>   property or the Find(String) method, the Tag property will contain the
>   previously set data. This property is only used by the calling
>   application and is ignored by the system. The maximum length of this
>   property is 4000 characters, but it is recommended that you keep the
>   size of the data smaller in order to improve performance.

Comment: I've tried that already..! but nop, that's not working... it gives `Error 400 Bad Request` and completes unsuccessfully. Thanks for your inputs anyway..