# How to handle Events for "HttpClient" in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

The below code is working in WP8 but when coming to WP8.1 the Events are not fired, What is the solution for handle the Events.

```
HttpClient wb = new HttpClient();
wb.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wcDownloadList_DownloadProgressChanged);
if (itm.LinkUrl.StartsWith("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="))
{
    wb.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wcYoutubeReadCompleted_OpenReadCompleted);
}
else
{
    wb.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wcDownloadList_OpenReadCompleted);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that starts the download?

Comment: Hello Peter Torr First of all how to fire a Event For httpclient

Comment: k But what about OpenReadCompleted Event

Answer (score 1):

**HttpClient do not support Progress Reporting**

The best way to go is using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. The first one supports progress.

I don't find an event `DownloadProgressChanged` in `HttpClient` in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Try using `webclient` for `DownloadProgress`.
[Difference between httpclient vs webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/need-help-deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient)

If you still need a `httpclient` to Progress Reporting you need to implement yourself .[Progress Bar with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient)

Comment: Hello Rohit and Eldho webclient is not supported in WP8.1 WinRt apps.

Comment: @Chinni we suggested for Httpclient.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called 
    // when the download completes.
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback2);
    // Specify a progress notification handler.
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
```

Event handler

```
private static void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
// Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...", 
    (string)e.UserState, 
    e.BytesReceived, 
    e.TotalBytesToReceive,
    e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Comment: WebClient is not supported in WP8.1 WinRt