# Can't Multi Download With WebClient

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webclient

I know this question has been asked before, but I have a special way I want to download the files through a webclient, I want to download each file at a time through a `Do While` statement, but it just adds the file to download and moves on to the next task that also downloads another file so it cancels each other out and crashes the application.

```
Private Function StartDownloads()        
        Dim wc As New WebClient
        AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgressChanged
        AddHandler wc.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadFileCompleted
        Dim delimiterChars As Char() = {"+"c}
        Dim words As String() = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(delimiterChars)

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i < words.Length)
            Dim delimiterChars1 As Char() = {"|"c}
            Dim words1 As String() = words(i).Split(delimiterChars1)

            Dim name As String = words1(0)
            Dim fileurl As String = words1(2)

            ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Downloading " & name & ":"
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(New System.Uri(fileurl), Path.GetTempPath() & "\" & name)
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
End Function
```

AND

```
Private Sub DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = String.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
        (e.BytesReceived / 1024D / 1024D).ToString("0.00"),
        (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024D / 1024D).ToString("0.00"))
    End Sub
```

So basically in the `Do While` statement it starts the download then continues without waiting for the download to finish and then downloads both at once, which then crashes the program/interferes with the labels displaying the download name, the reason this is a different question from others is I need it to specify the download name as I can't do with other tutorials, by adding the downloads to a list...

So if anyone can help me make the `Do While` statement wait for the download to finish then continue with the next without loosing the file name and stuff like that, please give me some tips, thanks!

I know that `DownloadFile` waits for the download to finish then continues, but I need it to show download progress and download bytes and stuff like that...

P.S. Sorry if this is confusing as it's hard to explain, thanks.

Comment: Try using `await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...)` instead of `wc.DownloadFileAsync()`, although it's not clear from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193917%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the events will fire in this case. If they don't, you'd either have a `DoEvents` loop after the call or switch to `HttpClient` and [implement progress yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20661652/11683).

Comment: @GSerg It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By adding `await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...)`, it worked perfectly