# libvideo download video with async method getting progress

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I am trying to download a video from youtube using [libvideo](https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo) and update a progress bar accordingly. I don't really know how to use its async method. Can someone provide me with an example?

```
var youTube = YouTube.Default;
var video = await youTube.GetVideoAsync(Url);
```

Comment: I think that you need to handle the progress bar stuff yourself. async/await in C# allows you not to block with I/O calls, but does not give you progress bars for free. You'll need to check for progress manually in a separate Task.

Comment: That is my problem, i have no ideia how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the project issues, you'll find that the library itself does not support getting progress. https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo/issues/47

If you want to code the progress bar yourself, I suggest helping with the issue of the aforementioned github project.

Other approach could build on top of this answer: [Progress bar with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient)
libvideo uses HttpClient class on background.