# Inform that a long running async task is in progress - the right way

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, progress

I have a console program which sends async HTTP requests to an external web API. (`HttpClient.GetAsync());`)
These tasks can take several minutes to complete - during which I'd like to be able to show to the user that the app is still running - for example by sending `Console.WriteLine("I ain't dead - yet")` every 10 seconds.

I am not sure how to do it right, without the risk of hiding exceptions, introducing deadlocks etc.

**I am aware of the IProgress<T>, however I don't know whether I can introduce it in this case. I am await a single async call which does not report progress. (It's essentially an SDK which calls httpClient GetAsync() method**

Also:
I cannot set the GUI to 'InProgress', because there is no GUI, its a console app - and it seems to the user as if it stopped working if I don't send an update message every now and then.

Current idea:

```
            try
            {
                var task = httpClient.GetAsync(uri); //actually this is an SDK method call (which I cannot control and which does not report progress itself)

                while (!task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000 * 10);
                    this.Logger.Log(Verbosity.Verbose, "Waiting for reply...");
                }
                onSuccessCallback(task.Result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (onErrorCallback == null)
                {
                    throw this.Logger.Error(this.GetProperException(ex, caller));
                }
                this.Logger.Log(Verbosity.Error, $"An error when executing command [{action?.Command}] on {typeof(T).Name}", ex);
                onErrorCallback(this.GetProperException(ex, caller));
            }
```

Comment: can't you `await` saying `await action.Action()`

Comment: @Rahul - of course, but this way I will wait for 5 minutes with no info for user...

Comment: What about implementing IProgress instead? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient

Comment: @BradleyUffner - thanks - but I don' think this is possible - I don't have any loop where I can show partial progress. It's just a call to httpClient.GetAsync(), which does not provide any callbacks

Comment: @Fildor - there is no GUI, its a console app - and it seems to the user as if it stopped working if I don't send an update message every now and then.

Comment: Ah, that Info would have helped a lot if you had mentioned it in the question. Anyway. In that case I'd probably use a Timer of some sort that checks the status of the Task instead of a "spin-wait".

Comment: @Fildor That isn't a spin wait, that is a Timer.

Comment: @Aron OK, let me rephrase. I would have implemented the timer differently. But as is, if it works, I don't really see a reason to change it.

Comment: @Fildor - yeah, indeed, I've been adding additional info to question as I read the comments:). So... Is there no issue with not 'awaiting' the main task?

Comment: @Fildor actually I would do the opposite, I would refactor `Timer` to the above code. The reason being is that the above code works correctly in WinForms, WPF and Console, given the above code using the `SynchronizationContext.Current`.

Comment: @Aron You are right.... that goes into my "neat tricks" notebook.

Comment: @Aron - so, are you saying that the solution I have is OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me tidy this code up a bit for you

```
async Task Main()
{
    var reporter = new ConsoleProgress();
    var result = await WeatherWaxProgressWrapper(() => GetAsync("foo"), reporter);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}



public async Task<int> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    return 1;
}

public async Task<T> WeatherWaxProgressWrapper<T>(Func<Task<T>> method, System.IProgress<string> progress)
{
    var task = method();
    while(!task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
    {
        await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(1000));
        progress.Report("I ain't dead");
    }
    return await task;
}

public class ConsoleProgress : System.IProgress<string>
{
    public void Report(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a never-ending `Task` as a beacon that signals every 10 sec, and cancel it after the completion of the long running I/O operation:

```
var beaconCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var beaconTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), beaconCts.Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Still going...");
    }
});
await LongRunningOperationAsync();
beaconCts.Cancel();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `System.Progress<T>`, a wonderful implementation of `IProgress`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1

You create an object of this class on the "UI thread" or the main thread in your case, and it captures the `SynchronizationContext` for you. Pass it to your worker thread and every call to `Report` will be executed on the captured thread, you don't have to worry about anything.

Very useful in WPF or WinForms applications.