# Get response for HttpCompletionOption ResponseHeadersRead

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I am trying to get progress of an api along with the response. `ResponseHeadersRead` works fine to get the progress but I can't figure out why it doesn't return the response.

**Download part**

```
public async Task StartDownload()
{
    _httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1), };

    using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_downloadUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        await DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(response);

        string strResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(strResp); // Doesn't print anything
    }
}
```

**Reading Stream part**

```
private async Task DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

    using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        await ProcessContentStream(totalBytes, contentStream);

    }
}
```

The code is actually from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169927/3480088).

I am just not getting the response. If I use `ResponseContentRead` I get response but it defeats the purpose of progress.

**EDIT**

**ProcessContentStream code** - This part read the response as it comes bit by bit and posts the progress in `TriggerProgressChanged`

```
private async Task ProcessContentStream(long? totalDownloadSize, Stream contentStream)
{
    var totalBytesRead = 0L;
    var readCount = 0L;
    var buffer = new byte[8192];
    var isMoreToRead = true;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(DestinationFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
    {
        do
        {
            var bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                isMoreToRead = false;
                //TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
                continue;
            }

            await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            readCount += 1;

            if (readCount % 100 == 0)
            {
                //TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
            }
        }
        while (isMoreToRead);
    }
}
```

**Post the progress**

```
private void TriggerProgressChanged(long? totalDownloadSize, long totalBytesRead)
{
    if (ProgressChanged == null)
        return;

    double? progressPercentage = null;
    if (totalDownloadSize.HasValue)
        progressPercentage = Math.Round((double)totalBytesRead / totalDownloadSize.Value * 100, 2);

    ProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead, progressPercentage);
}
```

`ProgressChanged` is a delegate method.

[Project link](https://github.com/rishabdutta/Progress)

Comment: _"but I can't figure out why it doesn't return the response."_ - probably because you already read the content in `DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage`? You're trying to read the same content twice. If you read to the end of the response with `ReadAsStreamAsync`, what else do you expect to find by calling `ReadAsStringAsync`? I would expect nothing.

Comment: Well I have to read the stream in order to get the progress. Once it's done I need to pass the response or read it as string. What to do in this case?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get the progress"? What does `ProcessContentStream` do?

Comment: C# doesn't readily make the download progress available to user. So you need to write your own download code by grabbing the stream. I need too show download progress to the user in case the file is big.

Comment: Then you need to return the response from your custom download method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169927/3480088 for `ProcessContentStream` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution. I needed to read the file on which I wrote the bytes as it was coming in with a `StreamReader`. Reading file with `StreamReader` has been explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples).

```
private async Task DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

    using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        await ProcessContentStream(totalBytes, contentStream);

        // Added code
        char[] buffer;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(DestinationFilePath))
        {
            buffer = new char[(int)sr.BaseStream.Length];
            await sr.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)sr.BaseStream.Length);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(new string(buffer)); // Now it prints the response
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the `ProcessContentStream` method code and the code where you assign the `DestinationFilePath` because as it is now looks like you are processing the stream from the response, but then you read from the filesystem and it's misleading taking into account the question.

Comment: That will become long but ok. Will do it.

Comment: You're using `StreamRader.ReadAsync` incorrectly: the method can return fewer characters than requested, so you need to use a loop - but a better idea is to just use `ReadToEnd` into a `String` directly. Also, if the response is binary data then this code is very wrong because a `char` in C#/.NET is a 16-bit value, not a `byte`. C# is not C.