# C# - Monitor Progress Httpclient once GetByteArrayAsync is called?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient, percentage, progress

I'm using .Net 4.5 version for this C# project and successfully **Implementing a Download** using this Code ([taken from zetcode](http://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/)):

> Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientDownloadImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var url = "http://webcode.me/favicon.ico";
            byte[] imageBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            string localFilename = "favicon.ico";
            string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, imageBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

- 1st Problem is : no way to implement percentage 0% until 100% from the async call. From **File.WriteAllBytes()** how to show the progress out into ant (int/double) variable or something?
- 2nd Problem is: when I checked on nu package manager, for the Library of System.Net.Http but the **versioning** is **strange**. Look at **the number** shown! It's not matched! 4.3.4 and 4.0.0 What is that?

[image: version]

Comment: Related: [Progress bar with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient)

Comment: Looked at a bunch of posts, not saying any of these work, as I've not tested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient (3rd answer seemed promising). HttpClient Progress extension - https://gist.github.com/dalexsoto/9fd3c5bdbe9f61a717d47c5843384d11. Have you looked at using `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`?

Comment: sure but your suggestion is by using System.Web instead of System.Net implementation of httpclient.

Comment: what about the versioning.... coz it's still the same case.