# Httpclient getting the download speed

Tags: c#, httpclient

could someone help me a little?
I'm downloading files and I'm able to get the actual download speed. but I want to change the UNIT from KB/sec to MB/sec if the speed is greater than 1mbps

How do I know if is greater than 1mbps so that I the UNIT will change as well

Here's my current code.

I'm running this in a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
     {
     
    string downloadUrl= LB.Items[i].toString();
    
    
    double currentSize = TotalFileSize; //882672
    string UNIT = "KB/s";
    
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
     

    await ProgressUpdate(downloadUrl, cts.Token); //the actual download
    
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    double t = Math.Round(currentSize / 1024 / (endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds);
    var downloadSpeed = (string.Format("Download Speed: {0}{1}", t, UNIT));
```

Thank you.

Comment: `if( t > 1024.0 ){ t /= 1024.0; UNIT="MB/s";  }` or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I think like  that. I'm gonna try

Comment: the unit still not changing. 1528KB/sec
still KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a little Helper, for example:

```
var downloadSpeed = FormatSpeed(TotalFileSize, (endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds);

string FormatSpeed( double size, double tspan )
{
      string message = "Download Speed: {0:N0} {1}";
      if( size/tspan > 1024 * 1024 ) // MB
      {
          return string.Format(message, size/(1024*1204)/tspan, "MB/s");
      }else if( size/tspan > 1024 ) // KB
      {
          return string.Format(message, size/(1024)/tspan, "KB/s");
      }
      else
      {
          return string.Format(message, size/tspan, "B/s");
      }
}
```

See it run: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MjUW2M

Output:

```
Download Speed: 10 B/s
Download Speed: 100 B/s
Download Speed: 200 B/s
Download Speed: 100 KB/s
Download Speed: 83 MB/s
Download Speed: 9 MB/s
```

Or a slight variation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqanaT

```
string FormatSpeed( double size, double tspan )
{
  string message = "Download Speed: ";
  if( size/tspan > 1024 * 1024 ) // MB
  {
      return string.Format(message + "{0:N1} {1}", size/(1024*1204)/tspan, "MB/s");
  }else if( size/tspan > 1024 ) // KB
  {
      return string.Format(message + "{0:N0} {1}", size/1024/tspan, "KB/s");
  }
  else
  {
      return string.Format(message + "{0:N1} {1}", size/1024/tspan, "KB/s");
  }
```

Output:

```
Download Speed: 0.0 KB/s
Download Speed: 0.1 KB/s
Download Speed: 0.2 KB/s
Download Speed: 100 KB/s
Download Speed: 83.1 MB/s
Download Speed: 8.5 MB/s
```

Comment: Wooow! gonna test it now

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked now. This is what I'm looking for.  How I can see the real time speed while downloading? the result only showing after the endTime

Comment: Depends on your exact code for the download. Are you using `HttpClient`? Maybe ask another question about this part and link it here. Then I'll have a look.

Comment: Yeah I'm using httpclient. Thank you.  I'll try first if I can do if not I'll post later my question

Comment: @zack123 This looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46497896/982149

Comment: Here's my new question regarding with the realtime download speed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64243271/httpclient-get-realtime-download-speed-while-downloading