# HttpClient ReadAsStringAsync with progress

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, stream, httpclient

Is there a way to get the progress of the `ReadAsStringAsync()` method?
I am just getting the HTML content of a website and parsing.

```
public static async Task<returnType> GetStartup(string url = "http://")
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How long is the string? If the response size is big enough to warrant progress information (i.e. sized larger than a few megabytes) then you probably shouldn't be reading it as a `String`.

Comment: Also, what kind of progress information are you after, exactly? For a response sized smaller than ~10KB (i.e. a couple of TCP packets/ethernet-frames) then it's impossible to get a numerical percentage progress figure because it will jump from 0% to 100% in a single go.

Comment: @Dai the string size is between 3MB and 10MB

Comment: Does the server send the `Content-Length` header in responses? Is it using `gzip` for `Transfer-Encoding` and/or `Content-Encoding`?

Comment: @Dai Encoding: gzip, deflate, br. No content-lenght header in response.

Comment: Without a `Content-Length` header it is impossible to indicate any kind of percentage progress.

Comment: @Dai Date, Content-Type, Server, Transfer-Encoding in headers in response...

Comment: None of those are relevant. `Content-Length` is required, without it you're SOL.

Comment: Actually, after testing, Content-Length is available. The file says it isn't there but it is.
I got a response of 5822400 so i guess it is working$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progress bar with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the progress of the `ReadAsStringAsync()` method? I am just getting the html content of a website and parsing.

Yes and no.

`HttpClient` does not expose timing and progress information from the underlying network-stack, but you *can* get some information out by using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, the `Content-Length` header, and reading the response yourself with your own `StreamReader` (asynchronously, of course).

Do note that the `Content-Length` in the response headers will refer to the length of the *compressed* content prior to decompression, not the original content length, which complicates things because probably *most* web-servers today will serve HTML (and static content) with `gzip` compression (as either `Content-Encoding` or `Transfer-Encoding`), so the `Content-Length` header will not tell you the length of the decompressed content. Unfortunately, while `HttpClient` *can* do automatic GZip decompression for you, it won't tell you what the decompressed content length is.

But you *can* still report some kinds of progress back to your method's consumer, see below for an example. You should do this using the .NET idiomatic `IProgress<T>` interface rather than rolling your own.

Like so:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _hc = new HttpClient()
{
    DefaultRequestHeaders =
    {
        { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" }
    }
    // NOTE: Automatic Decompression is not enabled in this HttpClient so that Content-Length can be safely used. But this will drastically slow down content downloads.
};

public static async Task<T> GetStartupAsync( IProgress<String> progress, string url = "http://")
{
    progress.Report( "Now making HTTP request..." );

    using( HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync( url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead ) )
    {
        progress.Report( "Received HTTP response. Now reading response content..." );

        Int64? responseLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
        if( responseLength.HasValue )
        {
            using( Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) )
            using( StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( responseStream ) )
            {
                Int64 totalBytesRead = 0;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: responseLength.Value ); // Note that `capacity` is in 16-bit UTF-16 chars, but responseLength is in bytes, though assuming UTF-8 it evens-out.

                Char[] charBuffer = new Char[4096];
                while( true )
                {
                    Int32 read = await rdr.ReadAsync( charBuffer ).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    sb.Append( charBuffer, 0, read );

                    if( read === 0 )
                    {
                        // Reached end.
                        progress.Report( "Finished reading response content." );
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progress.Report( String.Format( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Read {0:N0} / {1:N0} chars (or bytes).", sb.Length, resposneLength.Value );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            progress.Report( "No Content-Length header in response. Will read response until EOF." );
            
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
       
        progress.Report( "Finished reading response content." );
    }
```

Notes:

- In general, any `async` method or method returning a `Task`/`Task<T>` should be named with an `Async` suffix, so your method should be named `GetStartupAsync`, not `GetStartup`.
- Unless you have an `IHttpClientFactory` available, you **should not** wrap a `HttpClient` in a `using` block because this can cause system resource exhaustion, especially in server application.

  - (The reasons for this are complicated and also may differ depending on your .NET implementation (e.g. I believe Xamarin's `HttpClient` doesn't have this problem), but I won't go into details here).
  - So you can safely ignore any Code Analysis warning about not disposing of your `HttpClient`. This is one of the few exceptions to the rule about always disposing of any `IDisposable` objects that you create or own.
  - As `HttpClient` is thread-safe and this is a `static` method consider using a cached static instance instead.
- You also don't need to wrap `HttpResponseMessage.Content` in a `using` block either, as the `Content` object is owned by the `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: As I said in the comment above, Content-Length is available.
I guess I should go for ReadAsStreamAsync?

Comment: @Alejandro I have updated my answer to account for `Content-Length`.

Comment: You have too many typo mistakes. I cleared it up but you should also do it for the answer

Comment: @Alejandro The code in my answer is only intended as an illustrative example and it is not intended to be copied-and-pasted into production. **You should never be blindly copying and pasting code from StackOverflow - or any other website for that matter.**

Comment: I am not talking about me, I am talking about future references. I didn't really need any ReadAsStringAsync illustrative, my question was about ReadAsStringAsync not streamer.
I am accepting the answer as I am finding out there is not solution with ReadAsStringAsync besides using a streamer. Anyway, as you wish