# HttpClient progresschanged event

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to get progress while trying to download a big string.
Till now i am using WebClient.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
   var jsonString = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
}
```

Is it possible to create the same event in http client? I din't find anything so easy in internet.

Comment: Have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46497896/2030565

Comment: No but it looks so difficult to me. WebClient have just one single method for this

Comment: @Jasen whoops! I misclicked and selected the wrong one. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Here's another (the one I initially meant to link) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665200/2228526

Comment: I need to download a big string not a file

Comment: You'd still handle it as a Stream https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-do-i-generate-a-stream-from-a-string